# What can I do to improve this help/usage message?

Tags: help, command-line

I'm currently developing a command line tool for unix. Since it is good practise to provide a decent help/usage message I decided to work on it a little.

There are two variants of this message. The first that get's displayed when the user entered an invalid amount of parameters or none at all. The second message gets displayed when the program is called with `-h` or `--help`.

These are the two messages:

```
Usage:
  Display help:
    crackstation -h

  Create dictionary:
    crackstation -c [-v] [test]... [-r <Size>] [-q] <wordlist> <dictionary> <hashtype>

  Find hash in dictionary:
    crackstation [-q] <wordlist> <dictionary> <hashtype> <hashes>...

  Verify dictionary:
    crackstation -v [test]... [-q] [wordlist] <dictionary> [hashtype]

  List available hashes:
    crackstation -l
```

```
Usage:
  Display help:
    crackstation -h

  Create dictionary:
    crackstation -c [-v] [test]... [-r <Size>] [-q] <wordlist> <dictionary> <hashtype>

  Find hash in dictionary:
    crackstation [-q] <wordlist> <dictionary> <hashtype> <hashes>...

  Verify dictionary:
    crackstation -v [test]... [-q] [wordlist] <dictionary> [hashtype]

  List available hashes:
    crackstation -l


Modes:
  -h, --help,         Print usage and exit.
  -c, --create        Creates the dictionary from the wordlist.
  -v, --verify        Verifies that the dictionary is sorted.
  -l, --list          Lists all available hashes separted by a space character.

General options:
  -q, --quiet         Disables most output. Usefull for automated scripts.

Create options:
  -r, --ram=SIZE      How much RAM (SIZE MiB) to use for the cache when sorting the index file.
                      (Only used when -c is set).

Verify options:
  -a, --all           Enables all tests. If "wordlist" and "hashtype" are not specified all tests
                      requiring them will be silently skipped!
                      Equivalent to: -s -m
  -f, --fast          Enables all fast tests. If no tests are specified these tests will be run.
                      If "wordlist" and "hashtype" are not specified all tests requiring them
                      will be silently skipped!
                      Equivalent to: -s -m RANDOM_FULL

  -s, --sorted        Checks whether the index file is sorted.
  -m, --match[=MODE]  Tries to hash and then find all or some entries from the wordlist
                      (depending on the mode). See below for match modes. Requires "wordlist" and
                      "hashtype" to be specified!

Match Modes:
  ALL:                Go through the entire word list and do full and partial matching. (Default)
  ALL_FULL:           Go through the entire word list and only do full matching.
  ALL_PARTIAL:        Go through the entire word list and only do partial matching.
  RANDOM:             Pick random elements from the word list and do full and partial matching.
  RANDOM_FULL:        Pick random elements from the word list and only do full matching.
  RANDOM_PARTIAL:     Pick random elements from the word list and only do partial matching.

Examples:
  crackstation -c words.txt words-sha512.idx sha512
  crackstation words.txt words-md5.idx md5 827CCB0EEA8A706C4C34A16891F84E7B
```

Note: The beginning of the second is identical to the first. (In case you were wondering)

I myself understand really well what that messages means and how to use the program. The question is would a user too? And if not what to do? I'm also not too happy with the general outline. Specifcally talking about that the modes come right after the program parameters. Also I'm not sure whether the speparation of the parameters is good.
Further I am not very happy with the usage part. It seems bulky and unnecessary large to me. Any ideas on how to improve that?

One minor side question:
Even though I explicitly mentioned at the parameters `-a` and `-f` that all test requiring the wordlist and the hashtype will be silently skipped if specified I'm wondering if this behavior is so counter intuitive that I should instead print a warning when somebody tries to run a test that cannot be run and remove this message.

In case you want some further information on the project itself you can find it here: https://github.com/BrainStone/crackstation-hashdb

Comment: This isn't the right forum for this question. I'm not certain which forum would be.

Comment: @Mayo Why do you think so? It is a question about the user experience (of a program).

Comment: I could be pursuaded otherwise, but as I read this you've already answered the UX questions. "Should I give a help page? Is it important to give a comprehensive, readable help page? You answered "Yes" to both. Now the issue is how to implement it. At this point you are constrained in your formatting and it seems to me that the question becomes an issue of how clearly and accurately you describe your product.

Comment: @Mayo Text output and the formatting of it is as much UI you get in CLI applications. And as far as I understand this site is about the user experience of UIs. I'm trying to optimize the UE of my application.

Comment: @BrainStone While the question in general is on topic (in fact I'd like to see more CLI questions), what you're asking would have answers useful only to you.  We require that the answers be more broadly useful.  I suggest you ask a general question about an aspect of the UX that you're struggling with.  In the mean time I have to close it as it is more like a site review question right now.

Comment: Unix user here. This question is closed, but a couple of suggestions. 1) There are 3-4 required arguments (with a preset order). No other utility has that many. Pare them down to 1 or at most 2. Have e.g. `md5` default, override with an option. Read something from `STDIN` perhaps? 2) wordlist? dictionary? Why do you need to supply both? Are they different? They don't sound different. 3) `-l` is `separated by a space character`? Few other programs do that. Separate with a linebreak, like `iconv -l`. 4) The help output could (compactly) list valid hash types, assuming there aren't too many.

Comment: 5) How come in verify mode suddenly two of the three previously required arguments are now optional? How does the program even distinguish them from each other? If you supply a `-v dictionary hashtype`, how does the program know you didn't mean a `-v wordlist dictionary`? Oh, and what is that `[test]...`? 6) (continuing from #1) Just have specific switches for dictionary and wordlist and hashtype? I know it's more arguments but it gives a cleaner impression.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there are many people on here that understand your particular case to give you a firm answer as we're all UX designers and researchers so don't use the command line or Unix very much, if at all!

However, in UX we generally talk to our target users to find out how they feel about things like this.

You could try running a couple of tests with your target users:

1) Ask your users what they would expect to see in each of the scenarios you outlined (incorrect parameters and '-h' activation)

2) Ask your users what they understand from the outputs you showed here.

In each case you should get some insightful answers specifically geared towards your users and their understanding.